# Get text outside known element beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a webpage, and I don't want to use regex at all. I am using beautifulsoup to handle the scraping. I have this source:

```
<TD WIDTH="50%" VALIGN="TOP"><span class="sections">Date:</span>
13 August 2014
      <br>&nbsp;<br><span class="sections">Application Deadline:</span>
     <font color="maroon">
      28 August  2014</font>

      <font color="#990066">Application closed / under review</font>

<br>&nbsp;<br><span class="sections">Duty Station:&nbsp;</span>
Multiple duty stations
<br>
&nbsp;
```

From this source, I want to scrape **13 August 2014**.

I can find the span element searching by it's class with: `soup.findAll('span',{'class':'sections'}` get the first element, and check if the text is "Date:" but this is just giving me the element. The text that I'm trying to get is under it, and the only thing I can do is searching by the `td` but that's not what I want, because there are a lot of elements and text inside one `td`.

I know that I could do it using regex, but I'm really trying to do it just with beautifulsoup.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

Once I get the element `<span class="sections">Date:</span>`
I have to do `element.nextSibling`
Easier than I thought.