# HTML scraping using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have following HTML file and I am trying to scrape the complete sentence using BeautifulSoup but couldn't get it. Currently I am getting only highlighted words. my desired output should be

> Antenna booster has stopped sending signal files ,possible user network issue or BOOSTER issue.

Any solution?

```
  </table>
  <!--Record Header End-->
  <span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff; color: #ffffff">
   Antenna
  </span>
  <span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff; color: #ffffff">
   booster
  </span>
  has stopped
  <span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff; color: #ffffff">
   sending
  </span>
  signal files ,possible user
  <span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff; color: #ffffff">
   network
  </span>
  <span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000">
   issue
  </span>
  or BOOSTER
  <span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000">
   issue
  </span>
  .
  <br>
   <br>
    <br>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
issue_field = soup.find_all('span', {'style':'BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff; color: #ffffff'}) 
issue_str = str(issue_field) 
Issue_corpora = [word.lower() for word in BeautifulSoup(issue_str,'html.parser').get_text().strip().sp‌​lit(',')]
print(Issue_corpora)
```

Comment: Show the `bs` code you've tried.

Comment: issue_field = soup.find_all('span',
                            {'style':'BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff; color: #ffffff'})
issue_str = str(issue_field)
Issue_corpora = [word.lower() for word in 
                 BeautifulSoup(issue_str,'html.parser').get_text().strip().split(',')]
print(Issue_corpora)

Comment: Maybe you regex (`re`) would be enough for your needs in this case: `re.sub('<?.*>', '', t).replace('\n', '')`

Comment: I want output as --> Antenna booster has stopped sending signal files ,possible user network issue or BOOSTER issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are texts outside the elements. 
There is a duplicate question on SO already: [Get text outside known element beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621119/get-text-outside-known-element-beautifulsoup)

So here is the solution, maybe needs a little polishing.
(note that variable `t` contains the html as text)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(t)
text = ''
for span in soup.findAll('span'):
    text += getattr(span, 'text', '').strip() + ' '
    text += getattr(span, 'nextSibling', '').strip() + ' '
```

Result using this approach is:

```
>>> In : text
>>> Out: u'Antenna  booster has stopped sending signal files ,possible user network  issue or BOOSTER issue . '
```

You can replace doubled spaces with a single space or remove space before comma or define rules to handle it while looping through `span` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re 

example = """your example""" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")

_text = ""
for span in soup.find_all('span', style=re.compile('BACKGROUND-COLOR:')):
    _text += "%s %s" % (span.get_text(strip=True), span.next_sibling.replace("\n", ""))

print (re.sub(" +"," ", _text))
```

Use `re` in the end to trim extra spaces.

Outputs:

> Antenna booster has stopped sending signal files ,possible user network issue or BOOSTER issue .